# How to find a condition which makes box topology have a better properties?

Tags: general-topology

Lately I've been working on box and product topology. I want to find some better conditions.Here is one of my thoughts.

There is an easy theorem about product topology.

$$ f:A{\rightarrow}{\Pi_{{\alpha\in J}}X_\alpha}\ \ \ \ \ \ f(a)=(f_{\alpha}(a))_{{\alpha}\in J} \\ \text{For each} \ {\alpha}, f_{\alpha}:A{\rightarrow}X_{\alpha}$$
If $\Pi_{{\alpha\in J}}X_\alpha$ has a product topology, then $f$ is continuous iff each $f_\alpha$ is continuous.

Now I am considering the box topology circumstance:
It is obvious that: If $f$ is continuous, then each $f_\alpha$ is continuous.
Now I want to find a better condition, which makes $f$ continuous when each $f_\alpha$ is continuous.

Could anyone give me some suggestions or examples?

Comment: That property characterizes the product topology.

Comment: A topology with better properties is a different topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a unique topology on $X=\prod_{j\in J} X_j $ such that

(1) For every $A$, $f:A\to X$ is continuous iff $f_j:A\to X_j$ are continuous,

which is the product topology.

Let $A$ be any directed set with a maximal element $1$. Consider the topology on $A$ generated by sets like $(\lambda,1]$ and sets like $ \{\lambda\}$ with $\lambda\neq 1$.

Now suppose (1) holds. (1) implies that,  $(\forall \{\lambda_\eta\in A\}_{\eta\in H})(\lambda_\eta \to \lambda\Rightarrow f(\lambda_\eta)\to f(\lambda))\Leftrightarrow(\forall \{\lambda_\eta\in A\}_{\eta\in H})(\forall j\in J)(\lambda_\eta\to \lambda\Rightarrow f_j(\lambda_\eta)\to f_j(\lambda)))$

Fix a directed set $\Lambda$ (which has no maximal elements) and a net $\{f_\lambda\}_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$. Equip $A=\Lambda\cup\{1\}$ with the above topology and define $f(\lambda)=f_\lambda$, $f(1)=f$.

First assume $f_\lambda \to f$. For every $\{\lambda_\eta\in A\}_{\eta\in H}$, if $\lambda_\eta\to \lambda$, then either $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda_\eta\to 1$ or $\lambda\in \Lambda$ and $\lambda_\eta=\lambda$ for sufficiently large $\eta$. Whichever it is, we have, $(\forall \{\lambda_\eta\in A\}_{\eta\in H})(\lambda_\eta \to \lambda\Rightarrow f(\lambda_\eta)\to f(\lambda))$. This shows $f_\lambda(j)=f_j(\lambda)\to f_j(1)=f(j)$ for every $j$ . The converse is similar.

Comment: +1. My edit was for a typo "continous" in the 1st sentence.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you! Mine too.